# A type "info" to get more results from functions

Tags: function, types, ocaml

I have defined some complex data types, for instance:

```
type drawer =
  { ...
    box: boxes list }
type table =
  { ...
    drawers: drawer list }
type room =
  { ...
    tables: table list }
```

And I want to define some functions of similar purposes but with different types of arguments, for exemple:

```
val compare_size_rooms: room -> room -> bool (* true: bigger, false: smaller *)
val compare_size_tables: table -> table -> bool
val compare_size_boxes: box -> box -> bool
```

One thing is that sometimes, due to different structures, 2 rooms/tables/boxes may be not comparable, therefore I hope the comparison could give me some extra information, besides just true or false.

My question is, whether it is a common way to define a type `info`:

```
type info =
  | Incomparable_Tables_One_foldable_Another_non_foldable
  | Incomparable_Tables_One_rectangle_Another_triangle
  | Incomparable_Boxes_One_in_paper_Another_in_metal
  | ...
```

And I make the functions as following:

```
val compare_size_rooms: room -> room -> bool * info (* true: bigger, false: smaller *)
val compare_size_tables: table -> table -> bool * info
val compare_size_boxes: box -> box -> bool * info
```

So that in those functions, I analyse 2 values, if they are comparable, the `bool` returns which is bigger or smaller, otherwise, `info` returns useful information of analysis.

This structure seems me not very common, could anyone tell me if it is usual, or to realize the same thing if there is a better way?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two objects you are comparing are not comparable, it is not advisable to return a boolean value as if they were comparable. Instead, you can raise an exception:

```
exception Incomparable_Tables_One_foldable_Another_non_foldable

let compare_size_tables a b = 
  if comparable a b then 
    a.size < b.size (* Or whatever you do *)
  else
    raise Incomparable_Tables_One_foldable_Another_non_foldable

(* val compare_size_tables : table -> table -> bool *)
```

The alternative is to use a variant return type which can be either a boolean (when the objects are comparable) or an information type (when they are not). For instance, using the Batteries library:

```
open BatPervasives

type info = 
  | Incomparable_Tables_One_foldable_Another_non_foldable
  | ...

let compare_size_tables a b = 
  if comparable a b then 
    Ok (a.size < b.size) 
  else
    Bad (Incomparable_Tables_One_foldable_Another_non_foldable)

(* val compare_size_tables : table -> table -> (bool, info) BatStd.result *)
```

In the latter case, you will have to `match` whether the result was `Bad info` or `Ok boolean`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, why couldn't I find any doc about Batteries library or BatPervasives on line or in the Ocaml manual?

Comment: Also are `OK` and `Bad` are constructors in `BatPervasives`?

Comment: Because it's hard to find on the web :-) http://thelema.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/ is a nice place to start.